# Подгрузка массива в tableView

Tags: xcode, swift, изображения, uitableview

Есть пользовательский массив, в который парятся данные. В массиве помимо текста, есть ссылки, которые в таблице преобразуются в картинки. 
Проблема в том, что когда листаю таблицу, в которой уже загружено более 2500 элементом массива, она естественно подвисает. Если делать загрузку асинхронно, то картинки накладываются друг на друга и это выглядит некрасиво.

Хочу спросить совета, оставить синхронную загрузку картинок, но сделать подгрузку массива, например каждые 20 ячеек? или же оставить асинхронно, но тут я думал ограничить скорость пролистывания самой таблицы, но пока не знаю как делать. 
Либо же может есть какой нибудь вариант, как я заметил в вк, картинки подгружаются поверх стандартной

**UPD:**
Массив с данными

```
class AddClass: Decodable {



var name500: String // Имя
var date500: String // Дата
var images: [Image]
var ima: String // URL картинок

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name500 = "name"
    case date500 = "release_date"
    case images = "images"
    case ima
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let conteiner = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    name500 = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .name500)
    date500 = try conteiner.decode(String.self, forKey: .date500)
    images = try conteiner.decode([Image].self, forKey: .images)

    ima = ""

}
}
```

Ячейка

```
cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].name500 // Имя

let url = URL(string: filteredData[indexPath.row].ima) 
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!) // Картинка
        }

cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Дата выхода: " + String(filteredData[indexPath.row].date500.dropLast(10)) // Дата
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы переиспользуете ячейку и во время переиспользования для ячейки вызывайте метод, в нем сбрасывайте данные и тогда у вас наслоения не будет.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

}
```

Для асинхронной загрузки изображений используйте **Kingfisher** https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: рад бы использовать библиотеки, но пробовал Kanna, Alamofire и вроде все устанавливается, но вот библиотеки не видит) делал как в описании, но увы, в чем проблема, не знаю, поэтому пытаюсь без библиотек

Comment: Владислав, погуглите пагинацию с примерами на swift

Comment: Да гуглил, все примеры с загрузкой цифр, которые в функции просто +1 добавляют имея например изначально 15 элементов. У меня же их сразу парится более 2500, причём не только текст, поэтому пока не понимаю, как подгрузить массив

Comment: @VladislavBublik покажите, пожалуйста, пример формирования ячейки.

Comment: обновил основной пост

Answer (score 0):

Используйте URLSession для асинхронной загрузки изображений:

```
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: { [weak self] url, response, error in
        if error == nil, let url = url, let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.image = image
            }
        }
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
```

Comment: ошибка на session во второй строке 
Ambiguous reference to member 'downloadTask(with:completionHandler:)'

Comment: Это пример. Адаптируйте его под свой код.